# ZulipMobile cannot connect to zulip server

Tags: filesystems

I have downloaded the Zulip App and Android App and tried to connect to my Zulip server.

Unfortunately, I am getting "Cannot connect to server"

I can connect by using desktop.

Comment: check your SSL and check this https://github.com/zulip/zulip-mobile/issues/2909

Comment: This question doesn't have enough detail to solve the problem. You should [edit] it to clarify what you're asking (provide relevant details, e.g, how you configured the server, server log files, etc.). See [ask] and unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5015/22812

Answer (score 1):

Usually this symptom means the certificate file you've configured on the Zulip server has an incomplete chain. The [Zulip docs](https://zulip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/production/ssl-certificates.html) explain:

> Your certificate file should contain not only your own certificate but its **full chain, including any intermediate certificates** used by your certificate authority (CA). See the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) for details on what this means. If you’re missing part of the chain, your server may work with some browsers, but not others and not the Zulip mobile and desktop apps. ...
>
> Just trying in a browser is not an adequate test, because some browsers ignore errors that others don’t.  Two good tests include:
>
> - If your server is accessible from the public Internet, use the [SSL Labs tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). Be sure to check for “Chain issues”; if any, your certificate file is missing intermediate certificates.
> - Alternatively, run a command like `curl -SsI https://zulip.example.com` (using your server’s URL) from a machine that can reach your server. Make sure that on the same machine, `curl -SsI https://incomplete-chain.badssl.com` gives an error; `curl` on some machines, including Macs, will accept incomplete chains.

It's particularly common for Android devices to reject these incomplete chains -- both the system TLS/SSL implementations that Zulip uses, and some browsers (usually Firefox, usually not Chrome).

(I work on Zulip.)